# Корректно ли сказать

Tags: грамотная-речь

Корректно ли  сказать: "что привело тебя к этому светлому будущему"?

Comment: Добавьте контекст, так как ситуация неясна. О каком светлом будущем идет речь? Это ирония, фантастика?

Comment: Я привёл эту фразу в качестве упрёка. Что привело тебя к этому. Подразумевая конечно соотношение прошлого и настоящего. В контексте иронии.

Answer (score 1):

Так сказать **можно**, зная или подразумевая, что собеседник долгое время планировал сложившуюся ситуацию, о которой говорящий только что узнал. Конфликта времён здесь нет, поскольку новую ситуацию иронически можно трактовать как наступившее для собеседника будущее, - это *его персональное будущее*. Он планировал себе будущее, и вот оно наступило - таким оно оказалось сегодня, твоё когда-то спланированное (светлое) будущее! Как же ты к нему пришёл? "Светлое будущее" можно употребить без кавычек, это давно прижившийся советский штамп, над которым широко иронизируют.

Answer (score 0):

Можно предложить такой вариант: ***Что привело тебя в это  "светлое будущее"?***

Привести (**куда? В.п.**) в светлое будущее, в это место, где ты находишься.

Кавычки обозначают **условность** названия, так как имеется в виду настоящее. а не будущее.